# EmberJs: Common RESTAdapter

Tags: javascript, rest, ember.js

I fully disagree with the approach of [jsonapi](http://jsonapi.org) on the JSON format. I personally would prefer the *old* REST style over:

**/outputs**

```
[
  { id: 0, ... }
  { id: 1, ... }
]
```

**/outputs/:id**

```
{
  id: 0,
  ...
}
```

Is there a community adapter which supports this style?

Regards,
Bodo

Comment: since ember-data is adapter agnostic you can define your own adapter which deals with the old REST style...

Comment: @intuitivepixel yes, I already looked at the implementation. Unfortunately this takes quite a lot effort and I hope for some existing library (recommendation)

Comment: it depends heavily on what backend technology you are using, what is your use case?

Comment: @intuitivepixel I am using NodeJs with MongoDb and since years I was using the above JSON format. (Can look on https://github.com/bodokaiser/bankingjs if interested)

Answer (score 0):

I hacked the origin adapter myself.

I currently only tested create and findAll but the rest should work too:

https://gist.github.com/bodokaiser/5858197